# Updating Chromium fails (times out) as Snap Package

Tags: snap, chromium

It downloads Chromium correctly, but then fails to configure it.

```
$ sudo snap refresh && alert; alert
[sudo] password for webdev: 
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "chromium" snap if present (run hook "configure": 
-----
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 10 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 4 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc: caching, new cache contents: 89 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/util: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cMap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/eot: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/eot/font-awesome: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/fonts-go: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 20 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/cabin: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/cantarell: caching, new cache contents: 5 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ebgaramond: caching, new cache contents: 10 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/font-awesome: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/fonts-hosny-amiri: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/freefont: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/gentiumplus: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ipaexfont-gothic: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ipaexfont-mincho: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ipafont-gothic: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ipafont-mincho: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/linux-libertine: caching, new cache contents: 13 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/lobster: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/lobstertwo: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/malayalam: caching, new cache contents: 7 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto: caching, new cache contents: 73 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/stix: caching, new cache contents: 29 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/stix-word: caching, new cache contents: 5 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/tlwg: caching, new cache contents: 58 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35: caching, new cache contents: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/svg: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/svg/font-awesome: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 84 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Gargi: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Gubbi: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Nakula: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Navilu: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Sahadeva: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Sarai: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/abyssinica: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/adf: caching, new cache contents: 41 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ancient-scripts: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arphic-bkai00mp: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arphic-bsmi00lp: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arphic-gbsn00lp: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arphic-gkai00mp: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/artemisia: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/asana-math: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/baekmuk: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/baskerville: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/bodoni-classic: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/comfortaa: caching, new cache contents: 3 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/complutum: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/croscore: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/crosextra: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu: caching, new cache contents: 22 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/didot: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/didot-classic: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ebgaramond: caching, new cache contents: 10 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/font-awesome: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-beng-extra: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-deva-extra: caching, new cache contents: 3 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-gujr-extra: caching, new cache contents: 5 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-guru-extra: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-kalapi: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-orya-extra: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-telu-extra: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-yrsa-rasa: caching, new cache contents: 10 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont: 
<exceeded maximum runtime of 5m0s>
-----)
```

Is there a known way around this, or is this a bug which I should report on Launchpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just experienced this & saw your post.

Rather than use launchpad, I posted at https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/trouble-updating-chromium-snap/23276

The issue, I just try again (*usually not straight away.. I assume it's related to the system struggling, so I'd explore what is using resources using `htop` or equivalent, resolve that issue or wait until whatever that is has completed, then try again*).

In all cases a later `snap refresh` works for me (*though it maybe a few tries before it works*).

For more detail, you can read my post at https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/trouble-updating-chromium-snap/23276

(*my box is probably considered elderly, so it's a little resource challenged, and I at least see that as the cause, also how I use the box [inc. resource heavy browser extensions]*)

Comment: I haven't actually used that computer in the past couple of months. It will be turned on again soon, when I've moved house. I'll see what happens.